# Kotlin extension function with Generic doesn't work with Any?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, realm, extension-function

I want to have an extension function from the RealmList class:

```
private inline fun RealmList<Any?>.saveAll() {
    this.forEach {
        item -> Realm.getDefaultInstance().insert(item!! as RealmModel)
    }
}
```

But whenever I use it, this error appears:

[image]

Comment: It's because of "covariance". `RealmList<Accommodation?>` is not a `RealmList<Any?>` (in the latter you could put an `Int`, for instance)

Comment: Try `RealmList<out Any?>`.

Comment: Omg. Don't call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` like that. You have to pair every getInstance() call with a close() call, it's in the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that add **out** to generic declaration of your extension function.
It would work if such declaration was stated in the `RealmList`

```
private inline fun RealmList<out Any?>.saveAll() {
    this.forEach {
        item -> Realm.getDefaultInstance().insert(item!! as RealmModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg. Don't call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` like that. You have to pair every getInstance() call with a close() call, it's in the docs

Answer (score 2):

Your code is generally unsafe. Please fix your code, read the documentation, stuff like that.

Also, RealmList expects `? extends RealmModel`, so you need to use `T: RealmModel` with `out`.

```
fun <T: RealmModel> RealmList<out T?>.saveAll() {
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        val wasInTransaction = realm.isInTransaction()
        try {
            if(!wasInTransaction) {
                realm.beginTransaction()
            }
            this.forEach {
                item -> item?.let { realm.insert(it) }
            }
            if(!wasInTransaction) {
                realm.commitTransaction()
            }
        } catch(e: Throwable) {
            if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
                realm.cancelTransaction()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote, huh. Well, I'll see you around when you get `mmap failed(): out of memory size: 1048576 offset: 3145728`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use Realms method to insert instead of performing your loop? That way your extension becomes a simple call:

```
fun <T: RealmModel> RealmList<out T?>.saveAll() = Realm.getDefaultInstance().insert(this)
```

Comment: Omg. Don't call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` like that. You have to pair every getInstance() call with a close() call, it's in the docs

Comment: I just wrote that off top of my head, I still think this is weird since insert should be wrapped within a transaction.